# Compound two images as Node's background in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I can  add background image to Node through `background-image` attribute; but how to compound two images as background image of Node? @maxkfranz

Answer (score 0):

Only one background image is supported: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image

If you want to request new features, please use the issue tracker: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new

For now, you can combine your images in an editor and use the single background image as you wish.  Or, you can combine them programmatically using a canvas, and use the exported image from that on your node.